# Python logging MemoryHandler not passing logs to handler

Tags: python, logging, open-telemetry

I have this as python logging configuration in a project with the intention to batch the logs before printing it. But it seems none of the logs are getting printed..

```
logging.config.dictConfig({
        "version": 1,
        "disable_existing_loggers": True,
        "handlers": {
            "stream_handler": {
                "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
                "stream": sys.stdout,
                "level": "INFO",
                "formatter": "opentelemetry_formatter"
            },
            "opentelemetry_to_console": {
                "capacity":1,
                "class": "logging.handlers.MemoryHandler",
                "flushLevel": "DEBUG",
                "target": "stream_handler",
            }
        },
        "filters": {},
        "formatters": {
            "opentelemetry_formatter": {
                "()": OpentelemetryLogFormatter,
                "use_traces": True,
                "restrict_attributes_to": [],
                "discard_attributes_from": RESERVED_ATTRS,
                "meta_character_limit": 1000,
                "body_character_limit": 500,
                "resource_attributes": resource_attributes
            }
        },
        "loggers": {
            "": {
                "level": "DEBUG",
                "handlers": ["opentelemetry_to_console"],
                # "handlers": [],
                "propagate": True
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: I think the issue is with propagation..

Comment: Not sure why you think that. I have propagation turned on in my example too, but it's not needed to be specified - the default value is `True`.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me. This slightly modified script (since I don't have your specialized formatter):

```
import logging
import logging.config
import sys

logging.config.dictConfig({
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": True,
    "handlers": {
        "stream_handler": {
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "stream": sys.stdout,
            "level": "INFO",
            "formatter": "simple"
        },
        "memory_to_console": {
            "capacity":1,
            "class": "logging.handlers.MemoryHandler",
            "flushLevel": "DEBUG",
            "target": "stream_handler",
        }
    },
    "formatters": {
        "simple": {
            "format": "%(message)s"
        }
    },
    "loggers": {
        "": {
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "handlers": ["memory_to_console"],
            # "handlers": [],
            "propagate": True
        }
    }
})

logging.debug("Hello!")
```

when run, prints

```
Hello!
```

**Update:** So, it's probably an error in your special formatter. I'd set a breakpoint in its `format()` method and step through to see where it's going wrong.

Comment: Yes, but in my code I'm unable to do so.. what can be the issue? What can I provide to support debugging?

Comment: If I use only `stream_handler`, it works..

Answer (score 0):

Set level(not flushLevel) for MemoryHandler

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).